# VirtualBox: Disappointing performance of Windows 10 guest on iMac Pro

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox v6.0.6 on an iMac Pro running macOS v10.14.4. I'm dissatisfied with the behaviour of my Windows 10 guest for two reasons:

- by default the VirtualBox window only fills about 10% of my display, and I'm only able to significantly increase this proportion by scaling (leading to pixelation); and
- the VM is very laggy when attempting to play *Age of Empires II* via Steam.

[image: System overview]

I have allocated 16 GB of RAM and four CPU cores to the VM. I've tried both the VBoxVGA and VBoxSVGA graphics controllers with various video acceleration settings (none, 2D only, 2D and 3D). I currently have 128 MB of video memory allocated to the VM.

I have installed VirtualBox Guest Additions.

It seems a 2017 iMac Pro should be capable of running a computer game from 1999.

Can you suggest any settings changes that might improve my situation?

Comment: In general, virtual machines aren't for games. Even old games can have system requirements that easily exceed what the virtualization provides. And the only AoE 2 in Steam is https://store.steampowered.com/app/221380/Age_of_Empires_II_HD/ , a new (2013) re-imaging of the original game in HD. That said, with the Extension Pack (host) and Guest Additions installed the Windows VM should, at least, run in native resolution and smoothly. I suspect something is wrong with Virtualbox, Windows or both. But there are probably better virtualization software for Mac than Virtualbox (more later)

Comment: (cont.) However, running Steam for Windows inside a VM is really a bad idea, especially considering the alternatives: 1. Steam's own Vulkan: https://store.steampowered.com/news/37575/ You can run most of the Windows Games in Steam from other platforms; 2. Emulation with Crossover: Install the emulator then install Steam for Windows with the emulator.

Comment: Thank you, @GabrielaGarcia! I did not know about extension packs. After installing the extension pack on the host I am able to arbitrarily resize the VirtualBox window. I did not know about CrossOver. I installed it and used it to install Steam as you suggested. It worked beautifully. If you turn your comments into an answer I will upvote and accept the answer. :)